# python code running else statement even after if statement is true

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am learning python programming and was going through If Else conditions. **Even if the If statement is true, my code executes else condition.**

Please check the code below:

```
age = int(input("Enter your Age (in years)"))
sex = input("Enter you Sex(M/F)")
if(sex == 'M'):
    if(age < 20):
        print("You are just a teen.")
    if(age >= 20 and age < 25):
        print("You are a young man now.")
    elif(age >=25 and age < 30):
        print("You are a mature man now")
    else:
        print("You are getting old")
if(sex == 'F'):
    if(age < 20):
        print("You are just a teen.")
    if(age >= 20 and age < 25):
        print("You are a young woman now.")
    elif(age >=25 and age < 30):
        print("You are a lady now")
```

Over here, if i enter the age as 2 and sex as M, the code goes in first condition and prints the message

> "You are just a team"

Along with it, the code also run the else condition and prints

> You are getting old

I don't understand this behaviour. I checked for indentation and all indentations are correct.

Comment: `if` is not `elif`.

Comment: Is "teen" the right answer for age 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You accidentally made it a double if which would cause both statements to execute.

```
age = int(input("Enter your Age (in years)"))
sex = input("Enter you Sex(M/F)")
if(sex == 'M'):
    if(age < 20):
        print("You are just a teen.")
    elif(age >= 20 and age < 25): # notice now it is one if-elif block
        print("You are a young man now.")
    elif(age >=25 and age < 30):
        print("You are a mature man now")
    else:
        print("You are getting old")
if(sex == 'F'):
    if(age < 20):
        print("You are just a teen.")
    elif(age >= 20 and age < 25): # same here
        print("You are a young woman now.")
    elif(age >=25 and age < 30):
        print("You are a lady now")
```

Answer (score 1):

Switch

```
if(age < 20):
    print("You are just a teen.")
if(age >= 20 and age < 25):
    print("You are a young man now.")
```

with

```
if(age < 20):
    print("You are just a teen.")
elif(age >= 20 and age < 25):
    print("You are a young man now.")
```

What's happening is that your second if statement inside of if sex == 'M' isn't getting fulfilled because the age is not between 20 and 25. Since the elif isn't fulfilled either, whats inside the else block runs.

Answer (score 1):

In the code snippet you've given, the `else` is connected to the second if statement: `if(age >= 20 and age < 25):`. The first "if" executes fine, but then when the second "if" fails it executes the "else". This can be fixed by changing the second "if" to an "elif":

```
if(sex == 'M'):
    if(age < 20):
        print("You are just a teen.")
    elif(age >= 20 and age < 25):
        print("You are a young man now.")
    elif(age >=25 and age < 30):
        print("You are a mature man now")
    else:
        print("You are getting old")
```

Answer (score 1):

It is printing correct output. First, it is checking that age is less than 20 years, which is correct, it then print "You are just a teen.".

```
if(sex == 'M'):
    if(age < 20):
        print("You are just a teen.")
```

After that it checks second 'if' statement, then 'elif' and then it goes to 'else' and print that statement as there was no match previously.

```
if(age >= 20 and age < 25):
    print("You are a young man now.")
elif(age >=25 and age < 30):
    print("You are a mature man now")
else:
    print("You are getting old")
```

You may have made a typo here:

```
if(age >= 20 and age < 25):
    print("You are a young man now.")
```

Possibly, you are trying to use 'if' instead of 'elif' here.